# Is there a faster "Map"?

Tags: java, gwt

I have this GWT code below which have some slight problem:

It's either the `login` and `aboutme` property is set or just the `contacts` is set which ever comes first in the line. Could this be that the `contacts` property is set before the for-loop is finished, resulting in `contacts` being assigned a null?

```
public void copyFrom(User user) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (Contact contact : user.getContacts()) {
            map.put(contact.getType(), contact.getValue());
        }
        super.set("lastlogin", user.getLastLogin());
        super.set("aboutme", user.getAboutMe());
        super.set("contacts", map);
    }
```

Do I need to use a "faster" `Map`?

Comment: Actually this is a plain java question and has nothing to do with GWT.

Comment: What is the `super` in this case? Perhaps the problem lies there. You're looping thru a list of Contacts, putting them in a Map, then using that populated map to set a property. There is no reason that should behave strangely. The Map isn't the problem.

Comment: Actually, this is a GWT question because GWT is compiled into javascript - and part of the question, OP wants to know if there is an implementation that would run faster when compiled to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither a for loop, nor adding values to a `Map` are asynchronous operations, so that entire loop executes prior to the calls to `super.set(...)`. The `map`, in this case, cannot be `null`, since you instantiate it at the moment of declaration. It could end up being unpopulated (for instance, if there were no elements in `user.getContacts()`), but not null.

Your problem lies in the implementation of `set(...)` by whatever `super` is in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `get` on a Map for a key which does not exist `null` is returned, that's true. Your code is executed sequentially, so you can be sure that your for loop is finished when you access the `map`.

Comment: How do I know when the loop is done? Do you mean like I need to put some flag? I tagged this with GWT because I am not sure if the problem is with the fact that the actual code is compiled to javascript.